# phpmailer is not sending the activation mails to the registered users

Tags: php, email

I have user registration system & was sending the activation mails to the registered users
earlier but now the system is not sending the activation mails to the registered users:

```
<?php
/*~ class.phpmailer.php

/**
 * PHPMailer - PHP email transport class
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @author Andy Prevost
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 */

class PHPMailer {



  /**
   * Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low).
   * @var int
   */
  var $Priority          = 3;

  /**
   * Sets the CharSet of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  var $CharSet           = 'iso-8859-1';

  /**
   * Sets the Content-type of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  var $ContentType        = 'text/plain';

  /**
   * Sets the Encoding of the message. Options for this are "8bit",
   * "7bit", "binary", "base64", and "quoted-printable".
   * @var string
   */
  var $Encoding          = '8bit';

  /**
   * Holds the most recent mailer error message.
   * @var string
   */
  var $ErrorInfo         = '';

  /**
   * Sets the From email address for the message.
   * @var string
   */
  var $From              = 'root@localhost';

  /**
   * Sets the From name of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  var $FromName          = ' Webmaster,assamesesongs.org';

  /**
   * Sets the Sender email (Return-Path) of the message.  If not empty,
   * will be sent via -f to sendmail or as 'MAIL FROM' in smtp mode.
   * @var string
   */
  var $Sender            = '';

  /**
   * Sets the Subject of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  var $Subject           = '';

  /**
   * Sets the Body of the message.  This can be either an HTML or text body.
   * If HTML then run IsHTML(true).
   * @var string
   */
  var $Body              = '';

  /**
   * Sets the text-only body of the message.  This automatically sets the
   * email to multipart/alternative.  This body can be read by mail
   * clients that do not have HTML email capability such as mutt. Clients
   * that can read HTML will view the normal Body.
   * @var string
   */
  var $AltBody           = '';

  /**
   * Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of
   * characters.
   * @var int
   */
  var $WordWrap          = 0;

  /**
   * Method to send mail: ("mail", "sendmail", or "smtp").
   * @var string
   */
  var $Mailer            = 'mail';

  /**
   * Sets the path of the sendmail program.
   * @var string
   */
  var $Sendmail          = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

  /**
   * Path to PHPMailer plugins.  This is now only useful if the SMTP class
   * is in a different directory than the PHP include path.
   * @var string
   */
  var $PluginDir         = '';

  /**
   * Holds PHPMailer version.
   * @var string
   */
  var $Version           = "2.0.4";

  /**
   * Sets the email address that a reading confirmation will be sent.
   * @var string
   */
  var $ConfirmReadingTo  = '';

  /**
   * Sets the hostname to use in Message-Id and Received headers
   * and as default HELO string. If empty, the value returned
   * by SERVER_NAME is used or 'localhost.localdomain'.
   * @var string
   */
  var $Hostname          = '';

  /**
   * Sets the message ID to be used in the Message-Id header.
   * If empty, a unique id will be generated.
   * @var string
   */
  var $MessageID         = '';

}
```

Comment: If this was working bt is not working now, something has changed. What?

Comment: Didn't change anything just uploaded  a file php5.ini which is required to upload files by users more than 2 mb.My server is godaddy.

Comment: "just uploaded a file php5.ini" - so something changed. Try removing the file and testing the Mailer again. If it works there's something about uploading PHP.INI that's changing the effective configuration. "My server is godaddy" - get a better hosting company.

Comment: Removed the file but still its not functioning.